# Arduino - python read serial layout

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm using `pyserial` to read some values from my Arduino.
Using `serial.readlines()` gives me an array with all the values,
but these values look like:

- `b'l: steer left \n'`
- `b'r: steer right \n'`

How can I get rid of these `b'` and `\n'`?
Replacing them didn't work…

Comment: I strongly suggest you become comfortable with Python as a language before starting applications with Arduino.  Hands-on experience/experimentation is A Good Thing (tm), but you should have a pure understanding of the fundamentals before you start.  The Python maintainers have an [excellent tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial) designed for complete beginners – I suggest you start at [Chapter 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html).

Comment: Did you try using "print" with the value you get from readlines?

Comment: @FredS I thought the same thing you are thinking, but the data is binary. `print` will act just like `repr` in this instance.

Comment: Seems to work for me when I do "print" in python 2.7.  Maybe it's different in python 3+?

Comment: Maybe ... I'm using python3+ and it didn't worked that way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` is denoting the encoding the string is in – it isn't actually part of the string, so you can't replace it.  Similarly with each `'` – they denote that it *is* a string.  (`4` and `'4'` are two different things, but `print(…)` either of them and you'll get identical results.) The only thing you need to do is remove the last character (newline) with

```
myvar[:-1]
```

To re-encode the string, this should be sufficient:

```
b'string'.decode('ascii')
```

If you're using Unicode at all, use

```
b'string'.decode('utf-8')
```

instead.  See the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes) for more information to this end.

---

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 17:55:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'l: steer left \n'
b'l: steer left \n'
>>> _.decode('ascii')
'l: steer left \n'
>>> print(_)
l: steer left 

>>> exit()
```

Comment: Thanks - but maybe I should have explained it better ...
I know that I can remove the \n with your suggestion ...
However I need a clean output with no " ' ", no 'b' at the beginning ...

Comment: My answer stands as written; `b` is the *encoding* of the string; it isn't part of the string itself.